# Guard Against Database Context Change For SQL Connection Pool

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, hikaricp, mssql-jdbc

I have a collection of scripts that are being ran against a MSSQL database, some of these scripts set the database context to a different database other than what is used on initialization of the connection pool, other scripts expect the context to be what is set during initialization.

When a script modifies the database context and the connection is returned to the pool, the context switch that was performed persists across subsequent checkouts of that connection causing 'invalid object name' and similar errors in scripts that don't set the context themselves.

Is it possible to revert/reset database context switches when a database connection gets handed back to the connection pool?

I'm using HikariCP with the MSSQL JDBC driver, the following code outlines what is happening.

```
public class test{
  public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
    try(Connection cs = MyConnectionPool.getConnection();
        Statement st = ps.createStatement();
    ){
       // Context Switch
       st.execute("USE [msdb]");
    }

    try(Connection cs = MyConnectionPool.getConnection();
        Statement st = ps.createStatement();
    ){
       st.execute("SELECT top 1 * from [dbo].[filestats]");
      //"Invalid Object Name" failure because of the database context switch above
    }
  }
  
  private static class MyConnectionPool {
    private static MyConnectionPool mcp = new MyConnectionPool();
    private HikariDataSource ds;

    private MyConnectionPool(){
      ds = new HikariDataSource();
      ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=master";
      ds.setUsername("username");
      ds.setPassword("password");
      ds.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      ds.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws IOException {
      returns MyConnectionPool.mcp.ds.getConnection();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could set  it back to the default in your static getConnection() function.

Comment: You should avoid executing statements like `USE ...` in JDBC. It is recommend to use the methods like `setCatalog` (or `setSchema`) for this, although I'm not sure if HikariCP actually is able to reset those.